# Navbar expansível

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tenho essa `navbar` na parte esquerda da minha tela

```
<div class="main-menu">
  <ul>


   <li>
      <a href="listCadastro.php" onclick="">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-lg"></i> 
        </span>
        <span class="text">
          Cadastros 
        </span>
        <span class="menu-hover"></span>
      </a>
    </li>  
    <li>
      <a href="listCadastro.php" onclick="">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-lg"></i> 
        </span>
        <span class="text">
          Informações 
        </span>
        <span class="menu-hover"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="listCadastro.php" onclick="">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-lg"></i> 
        </span>
        <span class="text">
          Cartas 
        </span>
        <span class="menu-hover"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="listCadastro.php" onclick="">
        <span class="menu-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-lg"></i> 
        </span>
        <span class="text">
          Relatórios 
        </span>
        <span class="menu-hover"></span>
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Gostaria de adicionar `submenus` de forma que quando clicasse em cadastros por exemplo, esse `submenus` apareceriam embaixo do botão de cadastros, enquanto os outros botões iriam pra baixo.
Há alguma forma de fazê-lo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) do próprio bootstrap para fazer isso. Seu exemplo ficaria da seguinte forma:

```html
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
<body>
  
          <div class="list-group panel">
              <a href="#submenu1" class="list-group-item sub-item collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#submenu1">Cadastros <span class=" menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
                  <div class="list-group-submenu collapse" id="submenu1" style="height: 0px;">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">Cadastro 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">Cadastro 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">Cadastro 3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">Cadastro 4</a>
                  </div>
             <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menupos1" class="list-group-item sub-item">Informações </a>
             <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menupos1" class="list-group-item sub-item">Cartas </a>
             <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menupos1" class="list-group-item sub-item">Relatórios</a>

</div></body></html>
```

Veja esse [exemplo no JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/2y5bxphu/)

Fonte: [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/1u6VW4bsrR)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Por algum motivo eu não estava sabendo usar o collapse dentro do meu código. Obrigado.